# Properly formatting a local UTC date string when dealing with an Arabic locale

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and moment-timezone to get a local utc date string. I've created the function below to achieve this. When trying to use this when dealing with an Arabic locale I'm getting invalid date returned.

```
function _getLocalUtcDateString(utcDateString, timezoneId) {
    var utcMoment = moment.utc(utcDateString, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
    var localTimeTz = moment.utc(utcMoment).tz(timezoneId).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
    return localTimeTz;
}
```

If I call it with the following parameters `_getLocalUtcDateString("11/2/2016 4:45:47 PM", "America/New_York")` and set `moment.locale('ar')` it fails with invalid date. The problem seems to be with `utcMoment`, when the lacale is Arabic this value equals `١١/٠٢/٢٠١٦ ٠٤:٤٥:٤٧ ص` which is causing `moment.utc(utcMoment).tz(timezoneId).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');` to fail.

Comment: Why are you formatting a string in Arabic using a US format? If this is for Arabic readers in the US, then the locale is US and the language is Arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the console, you will see the following warning message:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

So the problem is the you are trying to parse a string that isn't in a recognized ISO format (see [parsing docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) for additional infos).

To fix the issue, you can simply remove the unnecessary `format()` in the first line of your function, as shown in the following working snippet:

```js
function _getLocalUtcDateString(utcDateString, timezoneId) {
    var utcMoment = moment.utc(utcDateString, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
    var localTimeTz = moment.utc(utcMoment).tz(timezoneId).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
    return localTimeTz;
}

moment.locale('ar');
var res = _getLocalUtcDateString("11/2/2016 4:45:47 PM", "America/New_York");
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```